# understanding stack and frame pointer

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I am trying to understand the stack and frame pointer. I have the simple C program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int myfunction(int counter) {
    int result = 5;
    printf("myfunction %p %p %p\n", &result, &counter, __builtin_frame_address(0));
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("main %p %p\n", &i, __builtin_frame_address(0));

    myfunction(4);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program using gdb and inspect the memory location starting with the address of the builtin frame I get the following output :
[image]

This is causing my confusion. I assumed the FP which has the address `0xbffff608` will point to the starting address of the stack as a result I expected that `result` and `counter` would have memory addresses starting higher or lower than the FP address, but this is the order of the memory addresses which are not following the assumption I had, could someone please help in clarifying this?

The memory addresses:

- 0xbffff608 (builtin frame address, I assume this is the frame pointer)
- 0xbffff610 (address of the counter argument)
- 0xbffff5f8 (address of the result variable)

What confuses me is that I thought frame pointer indicates the starting address of the stack, thus in this case 0xbffff608 points to the starting address of the current stack, then the counter and result in the current stack should all start after or before the frame pointer. But, now it is mixed. counter has a memory address higher than frame pointer while result has a memory address lower than the frame pointer. If the frame pointer indicates the start of the stack, why is then the situation?

Update: main function disassembly

[image]

Comment: Nitpick: When printing a pointer it should be casted to void-pointer

Comment: Which system? I can't reproduce on my system

Comment: its linux ubuntu 32-bit

Comment: okay, 32 bit system... well, I'm not 100% sure as I use 64 bit systems but as far as I known, the call convention for 32 bit system require the caller to place the argument on the stack **before** doing the function call. That would explain the location of `count` Did you look at the generated assembly? Look for `push` before the call.

Comment: I do see a push call right before the call to `myfunction` what does `$0x4` mean though? Is that the argument integer 4 being pushed?

Comment: Yes, it is.... So `count` is simply placed on the stack before the function call (note: on 64 bit it is passed using a register)

Comment: Read the [abi386](http://sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) specification. Invoke [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S yoursource.c` and look inside the generated `yoursource.s` assembler file. Read also the [Linux assembly howto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Assembly-HOWTO/) if that is allowed to you

Comment: If you also dump `myfunction` it should be possible to see that it takes `count` from the stack location related to `push $0x4`

Answer (score 1):

The exact use of the frame pointer is system and compiler dependent, but the observations can be explained as follows:

The difference between `counter` and `result` is that `counter` is an argument which is pushed on the stack by the caller (`main()`) while `result` is a local variable belonging strictly to the function (`myfunction()`).

Only `result` belongs to the function frame because the function only takes responsibility for cleaning up its own local variables while arguments are cleaned up by the caller.

It makes good sense that the caller has responsibility for cleaning up arguments since the size of arguments may not be constant (e.g. `printf()`).

Answer (score 0):

The order of the stack is

1. paramters
2. return address
3. base pointer
4. local variables

At <+11> you can see that ebp = esp the same will happen for myFunction.
If you look at the order you notice that parameters have higher addresses. Thats why counter has higher address and result lower.